# Scipy hierarchical clustering appropriate linkage method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

Apologies because I asked a similar question yesterday but I feel my question lacked content, hopefully now it will be easier to understand.

I have a symmetric matrix with pairwise distances between individuals (see below), and I want to cluster groups of individuals in a way that *all* members of a cluster will have pairwise distances of zero. I have applied scipy.cluster.hierarchy using different linkage methods and clustering criteria for this but I don't get my expected results. In the example below I would argue that ind5 shouldn't be part of the cluster #1 because it's distance to ind9 is 1 and not 0.

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(infile1, sep = '\t', index_col = 0)
print(df)

      ind1  ind2  ind3  ind4  ind5  ind6  ind7  ind8  ind9
ind1     0    29    27     1     2     1     2     1     1
ind2    29     0     2    30    31    29    31    30    30
ind3    27     2     0    28    29    27    29    28    28
ind4     1    30    28     0     0     0     1     2     0
ind5     2    31    29     0     0     0     2     2     1
ind6     1    29    27     0     0     0     1     2     0
ind7     2    31    29     1     2     1     0     3     1
ind8     1    30    28     2     2     2     3     0     2
ind9     1    30    28     0     1     0     1     2     0

X = squareform(df.to_numpy())
print(X)

[29 27  1  2  1  2  1  1  2 30 31 29 31 30 30 28 29 27 29 28 28  0  0  1
  2  0  0  2  2  1  1  2  0  3  1  2]

Z = linkage(X, 'single')
print(Z)

[[ 3.  4.  0.  2.]
 [ 5.  9.  0.  3.]
 [ 8. 10.  0.  4.]
 [ 0. 11.  1.  5.]
 [ 6. 12.  1.  6.]
 [ 7. 13.  1.  7.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  2.]
 [14. 15. 27.  9.]]

max_d = 0
clusters = fcluster(Z, max_d, criterion='distance')
sample_list = df.index.to_list()
clust_name_list = clusters.tolist()
result = pd.DataFrame({'Inds': sample_list, 'Clusters': clust_name_list})
print(result)

   Inds  Clusters
0  ind1         2
1  ind2         5
2  ind3         6
3  ind4         1
4  ind5         1
5  ind6         1
6  ind7         3
7  ind8         4
8  ind9         1
```

I was hoping that anybody more familiar with these methods could advice whether there is any linkage method that would exclude from the cluster any element (in this case ind5) with distance > 0 to at least one of the other elements in the cluster.

Thanks for your help!

Gonzalo

Answer (score 1):

You can reinterpret your problem as the problem finding [*cliques*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) in a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)). The graph is obtained from your distance matrix by interpreting a distance of 0 as creating an edge between two nodes.  Once you have the graph, you can use [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) (or some other graph theory library) to find the cliques in the graph.  The cliques in the graph will be the sets of nodes in which *all* the pairwise distances in the clique are 0.

Here is your distance matrix (but note that your distances do not satisfy the triangle inequality):

```
In [136]: D
Out[136]: 
array([[ 0, 29, 27,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  1],
       [29,  0,  2, 30, 31, 29, 31, 30, 30],
       [27,  2,  0, 28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 28],
       [ 1, 30, 28,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  0],
       [ 2, 31, 29,  0,  0,  0,  2,  2,  1],
       [ 1, 29, 27,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  0],
       [ 2, 31, 29,  1,  2,  1,  0,  3,  1],
       [ 1, 30, 28,  2,  2,  2,  3,  0,  2],
       [ 1, 30, 28,  0,  1,  0,  1,  2,  0]])
```

Convert the distance matrix to the adjacency matrix `A`:

```
In [137]: A = D == 0

In [138]: A.astype(int)  # Display as integers for a more compact output.
Out[138]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Create a networkx graph `G`, and find the cliques with [`nx.find_cliques`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques):

```
In [139]: import networkx as nx

In [140]: G = nx.Graph(A)

In [141]: cliques = nx.find_cliques(G)

In [142]: list(cliques)
Out[142]: [[0], [1], [2], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 4], [6], [7]]
```

(The values in the lists are the indices; e.g. the clique `[2]` corresponds to the set of labels `['ind3']`.)

Note that there are two nontrivial cliques, [3, 5, 8] and [3, 5, 4], and 3 and 5 occur in both.  This is a consequence of your distances having this anomalous data: distance(ind5, ind4) = 0, and distance(ind4, ind9) = 0, but distance(ind5, ind9) = 1 (i.e. the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Metric_space) is not satisfied).  So, by your definition of a "cluster", there are two possible nontrivial clusters: [ind4, ind5, ind9] or [ind4, ind5, ind6].

Finally, note the warning in the [networkx documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/clique.html): "Finding the largest clique in a graph is NP-complete problem, so most of these algorithms have an exponential running time". If your distance matrix is large, this calculation could take a very long time!

Comment: Hi Warren,

This is great, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. Indeed, the fact that the triangle inequality is not satisfied is what's complicating the task at hand --and I see now that it can produce more than one correct answer. However, using graphs seems to be the way to go forward.

Very helpful stuff, thanks again!

Gonzalo

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct!

You are getting the following clusters:

- cluster **1** with elements *ind4*, *ind5*, *ind6* and *ind9* (at distance 0 from each other).
- cluster **2** with element *ind1*
- cluster **3** with element *ind7*
- cluster **4** with element *ind8*
- cluster **5** with element *ind2*
- cluster **6** with element *ind3*

Only the elements at distance 0 are clustered together in cluster 1, as you require. Clusters 2 to 6 are *degenerate* clusters, with a single isolated element.

Let's modify the distances so that more proper clusters are created:

```
X = np.array([ 0, 27,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  1,
                   2, 30, 31, 29, 31, 30, 30,
                      28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 28,
                           0,  0,  1,  2,  0,
                               0,  2,  2,  1,
                                   1,  2,  0,
                                       0,  1,
                                           2])
Z = linkage(X, 'single')
max_d = 0
clusters = fcluster(Z, max_d, criterion='distance')
print("Clusters:", clusters)
for cluster_id in np.unique(clusters):
    members = np.where(clusters == cluster_id)[0]
    print(f"Cluster {cluster_id} has members {members}")
```

Getting:

```
Clusters: [2 2 4 3 3 3 1 1 3]
Cluster 1 has members [6 7]
Cluster 2 has members [0 1]
Cluster 3 has members [3 4 5 8]
Cluster 4 has members [2]
```